# Using a RSA signature to confirm the sender of a physical letter?

Tags: rsa, signature

(1) Alice wants to send Bob a physical letter.

(2) Alice also wants Bob to be confident that she sent the letter and not an imposter.

(3) Alice is confident that a potential imposter will not be able to intercept any letter she sends.

(4) Alice has previously in-person provided Bob a RSA Public key.

Can Alice use a RSA Signature to confirm she sent the letter?

What is the best approach Alice can take, that makes such verification as easy as possible for Bob?

Comment: See David Naccache and Jacques Stern, [_signing on a postcard_](https://www.di.ens.fr/~stern/data/St86.pdf), published in [proceedings of FC2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45472-1_9).

Answer (score 2):

A QR code can hold a bit over 2kiB. That's plenty for a short letter and a signature. If more is needed, use more than one QR code, and number them for ease of use.